# Gradle stuck syncing for project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project that somehow got suck in a gradle sync that I cant get out of.

All my other projects are fine its just this one that has the issue on my computer. I can pull the project down on another and not have this issue so it seems it only happens on my macbook

I deleted the user/.gradle folder

I deleted the projects .gradle folder and .build folders Invalidated cache and restarted Android Studio

Deleted the project completely from my computer and completely re-imported the project from source control

None of the things I have tried seemed to have worked. Does anyone have any ideas on how to stop this gradle sync issue?

Comment: 1. Would you please post all your gradle files. viz. (a)build.gradle [App level and Project Level} (b)gradle.wrapper.properties (c)gradle.properties (d) settings.gradle 2.Secondly also share share screenshot of how the build gets stuck. 3. Do you see any error in Logcat 4.Is there any issue with Internet as Gradle build uses Internet to download .pom dependencies file

Comment: Try to remove the project workspace from your system. For mac you can go to -> `~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio/Workspace/YourProject.xml` remove this and restart your A.S. this should work

Comment: Are you sure this is not this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66128407/empty-kmm-project-is-stuck-with-gradle-sync/66134425#66134425

Comment: @shadowsheep that seems to have done the trick!

Comment: Glad to know! ;)