# Android Studio stuck at gradle sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I somehow broke my Android Studio and I am not able to find a solution.

I am using Android Studio an a mac for a multiplatform kotlin project and recently updated to 4.1.3

The problem I am now facing is, that gradle sync never finishes (or my feeling is, that it acutally finishes but never tells Android Studio).

Android Studio behaves completely normal. It says "Gradle sync started" in the log, I see the loading bar where it does a bunch of stuff, until it eventually goes to "indexing..." and then finishes.
That would be the point where it usually finished Gradle sync in the log. But it just doesnt. It stops loading without ever finishing.
That is my Event Log:

> 17:29 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 17:29 * daemon started successfully
>
> 17:32 Gradle sync started

Also the Android Project list is stuck in "loading...".

[image]

When I open the same project on a windows machine, everything is fine. Also, the problem persists in a cmpletely newly created project as well.

I tried restarting the computer, deleting the ".gradle" folder and / or the ".android" folder and using the "Invalidate and restart" option several times.
I have also reinstalled Android Studio.
Nothing seems to help.

It seems to me that there is an additionnal config folder that is broken.

Does anybody have an idea what I can do to fix my issue?

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty KMM project is stuck with gradle sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66128407/empty-kmm-project-is-stuck-with-gradle-sync)

Comment: Ah! Dont know how I didnt stumble over this. Thank you! I will try on monday and comfirm again but it looks like that is the solution to my problem. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43980) of `AS 4.1.x`  works correctly only with `KMM plugin 0.2.0` and `Kotlin 1.4.2*`

Probably you have updated your kotlin version or your kotlin plugin version.

Check it out.